# How to retrieve username, password and roles from a database instead of retrieving them from tomcat-user.xml while using container-managed security

Tags: security, tomcat, container-managed

I have a web application which i deploy in Tomcat. I want to secure all pages under the url path *administration/**.

I have set up container-managed security entering the next snippet in the web.xml file:

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>administrator</role-name>
</security-role>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>                
</login-config>  
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>AdministrationPanel</web-resource-name>          
    <url-pattern>/administration/*</url-pattern>            
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>         
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    <role-name>member</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

and  in $CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml i have

```
<user username="userA" password="userA" roles="administrator"/>
```

Everything is working fine. I get a login box and i can authenticate myself as userA.

However, i would like to be able to store new users directly by using the web application, change user passwords etc.

Is it possible to tell tomcat to get the users, passwords and roles any other way? For example a class which retrieves them from the database.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [it is possible](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/realm-howto.html#DataSourceRealm).

Comment: Please share some detail here as this links can break anytime.

Answer (score 1):

Or for the current Release [Tomcat 6 Realm Howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html)

Comment: Please add some details here from source material as this links can break anytime.